# Insert varchar with sql string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to make a EXEC in my sql with Transact-SQL, like:

```
set @name = 'test'
set @sql =  'insert into TempTable values('+@name+')'
EXEC( @sql)
```

but i can't insert a varchar in the sql string because i can't put ' into the string so it to knows that @name is a varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first declare the variable first with declare , set and then u can use it.
below the complete code :

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR (500)
SET @name = 'test';
set @sql =  'insert into TempTable values('''+@name+''')'
EXEC( @sql)
```

use (''') three quote to add your varchar.

Answer (score 0):

A simple insert statement like this does not need to executed using `Dynamic SQL`. you can easily achieve the same using the query below.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR (500)
SET @name = 'test';
insert into TempTable values(@name)
```

You can refer to the link below for more details on issues related to dynamic sql.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Please forget using `EXEC` when you are working with dynamic queries. In SQL Server you should use [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(500);
SET @name = 'test';
DECLARE @query = NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO TempTable VALUES (@name)';

EXEC sp_executesql
  @stmt = @query,
  @params = N'@name VARCHAR(500)',
  @name = @name
```

With this

- You can avoid unnecessary type conversions (INT -> VARCHAR, etc)
- Native data types could be passed
- A bit more secure (will not solve all the problems, but a bit bette, than injecting variable values into the query string)